# How to use GET in PHP with OneNote API?

Tags: php, get, onenote-api

I've got the [OneNote API PHP Sample](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISamplePHP) (thanks jamescro!) working with all the POST examples, but there's no GET example and I haven't managed to put together code of my own that works. Here's what I've tried without success:

```
// Use page ID returned by POST
$pageID = '/0-1bf269c43a694dd3aaa7229631469712!93-240BD74C83900C17!600';
$initUrl = URL . $pageID;   
$cookieValues = parseQueryString(@$_COOKIE['wl_auth']);
$encodedAccessToken = rawurlencode(@$cookieValues['access_token']);
$ch = curl_init($initUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $initUrl); // Set URL to download
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (! $response === false) {
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '<i>Response</i>: '. htmlspecialchars($response);
}
else {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '<i>Error</i>: ';
    echo var_export($info);
}
```

It just returns 'Error' with an info dump. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**:
As Jay Ongg pointed out, "there are necessary headers that are needed".
After adding more detailed error checking and getting a 401 response code, I added:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:text/html\r\n".
"Authorization: Bearer ".$encodedAccessToken));
```

... and could access the requested page.

Answer (score 2):

without information on the specific error I'm not sure what issue you are hitting. Try looking at the PHP Wordpress plugin here: https://github.com/wp-plugins/onenote-publisher/blob/master/api-proxy.php

look at what is sent to wp_remote_get - there are necessary headers that are needed.

Also make sure you have the scope "office.onenote" when you request the access token.

If you need more help, please add information about the specific URL you are attempting to call, as well as the contents of your headers. If you have any errors, please include the output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the WP plugin - I'll have a study of that.

I do have the necessary "office.onenote" scope.

'URL' is as defined in the OneNote API PHP Sample, i.e. 'https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages'

I'll add more error reporting.

Comment: By the way, I have updated the PHP sample to have a GET example.

Comment: Thanks very much, Jay Ongg. That's excellent - just what I was hoping for with my original question. Good to have your confirmation of the crucial addition of curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ...